# Diﬀerentiable maps and be unique linear map

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $\pmb F : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$
>   is diﬀerentiable at $\pmb a \in U$ and let $\pmb a $ is an cluster point of $U$  if there exists a linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m $ satisfying:
>   $$\big(\forall \epsilon > 0 \in \mathbb{R} \big) \big(\exists \delta_{(\epsilon,\pmb a)}>0 \in \mathbb{R}\big) $$
>   $$\text{such that} :$$
>   $$\parallel \big(\pmb x-\pmb a \big)  \parallel \leq \delta  \ \ \text{for every } \ \ \pmb x \in \mathbb{R}^n  \Longrightarrow \parallel \pmb F(\pmb x)- \pmb F(\pmb a) - T(\pmb x -\pmb a)\parallel \leq \epsilon \parallel \pmb x -\pmb a\parallel$$
>
> The map $T$ is unique, denoted $df_{\pmb a} $ and called ‘diﬀerential (or ‘derivative’) of $f$ at $\pmb a$ . Another notation for this is:
>   $$\pmb F(\pmb x)= \pmb F(\pmb a) + df_{\pmb a}(\pmb x -\pmb a)+\pmb r(\pmb x)$$

I have two questions :

$1-)$ How prove that $T$ is  unique ?

$2-)$ What is function of $\pmb r$ ? What is domain and range of function $\pmb r$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T'$ be another differential, $\|x-a\|\leq \delta_n$ implies that $\|F(x)-F(a)-T(x-a)\|\leq 1/n\|x-a\|$ and  $\|F(x)-F(a)-T'(x-a)\|\leq 1/n\|x-a\|$.

We deduce that $\|T(x-a)-T'(x-a)\|\leq \|(T(x-a)-(F(x)-F(a))+(F(x)-F(a)-T'(x-a)\|\leq \|F(x)-F(a)-T(x-a)\|+\|F(x)-F(a)-T'(x-a)\|\leq 2/n \|x-a\|$.

Let $b$ such that $\|x-b\|=1$, we have $\|\delta_n(x-b)\|=\delta_n$ impliest that $\|T(\delta_n(x-b))-T'(\delta_n(x-b))\|\leq {2\over n}\|\delta_n(x-b)\|$. This implies that $\|(T-T')(x-b)\|\leq {2\over n}$ for every $n>0$, we deduce that $(T-T')(x-b)=0$ and $T-T'=0$. Since for every $a\neq x$, $(T-T')({{x-a}\over{\|x-a\|}})=0$.

By definition, $r(x)= F(x)-F(a)-df_a(x-a)$.

Comment: Thanks . so function $r$ must be $r :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ .that's right ?